# how do I create the following json output

Tags: java, json

Using the **net.sf.json.JSONObject** and **net.sf.json.JSONArray** libs.

How do I achieve the following output?

```
[
  {
    marks: {
      show: true
    },
    data: [],
    markdata: [
      {
        label: 'First Mark ',
        position: 3,
        labelVAlign: "top"
      },
      {
        label: 'Second Mark',
        position: 9,
        labelVAlign: "top"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What did you try? Where are you having trouble? Show some efforts.

Comment: That is not valid [JSON](http://json.org). Seems like half the programming population thinks its JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far, where do you find a problem?

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject container = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject showMarks = new JSONObject();
    showMarks.put("show", true);

    JSONArray markData = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject firstMark = new JSONObject();
    firstMark.put("label", "First Mark");
    firstMark.put("position", 3);
    firstMark.put("labelVAlign", "top");

    JSONObject secondMark = new JSONObject();
    secondMark.put("label", "Second mark");
    secondMark.put("position", 9);
    secondMark.put("labelVAlign", "top");

    markData.add(firstMark);
    markData.add(secondMark);

    container.put("marks", showMarks);
    container.put("data", new JSONArray());
    container.put("markData", markData);

    array.add(container);
    log.info(array.toString(4));
```

Also, -1 for not saying what you tried so far and providing a slightly invalid JSON.

Comment: Ouch! Took a beating over that post. Still respect for the correct amswer.